# Looking for an example of using async for calling a web service in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, c#-5.0

I am looking for an example of using the new async keyword to call a web service in Silverlight.

This is the code that I'm trying to convert:

```
var client = new DashboardServicesClient("BasicHttpBinding_IDashboardServices", App.DashboardServicesAddress);
client.SelectActiveDealsCompleted += (s, e) => m_Parent.BeginInvoke(() => RefreshDealsGridComplete(e.Result, e.Error));
client.SelectActiveDealsAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always it yourself:

```
static class DashboardServicesClientExtensions
{
    //typeof(TypeIDontKnow) == e.Result.GetType()
    public static Task<TypeIDontKnow>> SelectActiveDealsTaskAsync()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TypeIDontKnow>();

        client.SelectActiveDealsCompleted += (s, e) => m_Parent.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (e.Erorr != null)
                tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
        };
        client.SelectActiveDealsAsync();

        return tcs.Task;
    }
};

// calling code
// you might change the return type to Tuple if you want :/
try
{
    // equivalent of e.Result
    RefreshDealsGridComplete(await client.SelectActiveDealsTaskAsync(), null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    RefreshDealsGridComplete(null, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to regenerate your service code with target version .Net 4.5. Then you can use the `async` keyword. Write some code like this:

```
var client = new DashboardServicesClient("BasicHttpBinding_IDashboardServices", App.DashboardServicesAddress);
// Wait here until you get the result ...
var result = await client.SelectActiveDealsAsync();
// ... then refresh the ui synchronously.
RefreshDealsGridComplete(result);
```

Or you use the `ContinueWith` Methode:

```
var client = new DashboardServicesClient("BasicHttpBinding_IDashboardServices", App.DashboardServicesAddress);
// Start the call ...
var resultAwaiter = client.SelectActiveDealsAsync();
// ... and define, what to do after finishing (while the call is running) ...
resultAwaiter.ContinueWith( async task => RefreshDealsGridComplete(await resultAwaiter));
// ... and forget it
```

Comment: Didn't work, I'm still only seeing the non-Task based versions. Also, "Service Reference Settings" dialog has the option to "Generate task-based operations" grayed out.